# Google Maps API KML layer change color for each layer

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I need help changing the colors for each KML layer and/or random colors the script is below for Google Maps Api. I enclosed the entire script below. I would like to know how to change the fill and border for each polygon and also generate random colors. This is a dynamic SQL script.  Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
function initialize() {
var soil = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 7,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.4098320, -85.2748718),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
select: "'col2'",
from: '1-nKJJErStEiMLY52mxzBxhjizorvs5ZXDJXu_IA'
},
map: map,
styleId: 1,
templateId: 1
});
var
ctaLayer = new        google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php?  format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=527031&BBOX=1,1,1,1',    {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new    google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php?   format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=527128&BBOX=1,1,1,1',    {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new   google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php?  format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=527489&BBOX=1,1,1,1',   {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php? format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=527504&BBOX=1,1,1,1',  {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php? format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=527505&BBOX=1,1,1,1',  {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php? format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=527560&BBOX=1,1,1,1',  {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new    google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php?   format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=528148&BBOX=1,1,1,1',    {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new    google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php?   format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=529859&BBOX=1,1,1,1',   {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
ctaLayer = new   google.maps.KmlLayer('http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/soil_web/export.php?  format=kmz&srid=4326&mukey_query=2396878&BBOX=1,1,1,1',   {preserveViewport:false});ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the colors of the polygons in a KmlLayer with the Google Maps API v3.  You can change your generated KML to set the colors.

See the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polygon)

- [PolyStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polystyle)
- [color](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#color)

[example of multiple KML files with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_easterngeek_linkto.html)

[example of changing colors (highlighting) with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_us_states_highlight.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to override the layer colors not the polygons itself. There must be a way to override a outside KML layer color?

Comment: Not with KmlLayer (at least currently).  If you import the KML into FusionTables, you can modify it in a FusionTablesLayer.  If you use a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)), that renders the KML as native Google Maps API v3 objects, you can modify their properties, but for complex KML may have performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like I have to use a third party since the data is dynamic and too large for the fusion tables. How would I write it with geoxml3?

Comment: Here is [one example with multiple kml files](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_easterngeek_linkto.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use geoxml3 for changing kml colors. Here is a link to that.. [see this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=VoterDistricts_address.xml)